# Creating a JRuby parser implementation to generate AST from java file

Tags: java, ruby, parsing, jruby, abstract-syntax-tree

I am currently trying to parse the following java code to get an AST from my .java files in a jrubyparser implementation:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class testDeposit {

    public void test() {

        BankApplication b = new BankApplication();
        b.deposit("11117", "10.00");
        assertEquals("330.00", b.getAccountBalance("Seetha"));

    }

}
```

However when I run the code, it gives me the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCbBN.png):

I have looked for the error information online but could not find anything regarding this error. Could anyone please explain what might be going wrong?

Thank you!

The following link is the repository for the jrubyparser that I am trying to use:
https://github.com/jruby/jruby-parser

Comment: What is you need? To parse from Java a Ruby program? Make this clear, please.

Comment: I realised what went wrong. It was because I assumed that the JRuby parser parsed both java and Ruby files but it only parses Ruby files. Does anyone know how I can parse Java files to create an AST?

Comment: Yes: Try [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org) or [JavaCC](https://javacc.java.net/). There are Java grammars for both of them.

Comment: Thank you! I have it working now!

Answer (score 2):

The JRuby Ruby parser complains because the code you are parsing is not valid Ruby. It looks rather like Java to me.